# i am Developing a signup page in asp.net but the code i am using to check if user already exists in database is not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

the following sql code i am using to check if user already exists in database
but it is not working 
and causing duplication of username in database.

```js
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SignUpConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkuser="select count(*) from [Table] where [UserName]='" +TextBoxName.Text+"'";
                SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                int temp=Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                if(temp==1)
                {
                    Response.Write("<span style='color:red;'>User Already Exists Please try another User Name</span>");
                }

                conn.Close();

            }

        }
```

Comment: The table where user is stored is really "[Table]". I would say it would be more likely "[Users]".

Comment: yes it is really Table that is why im using [ ]

Comment: Why aren't you using MVC and Asp.NET Identity?

Comment: @Jammer  it is my first web application in asp.net. i need to learn lot of things. can you suggest any guide like blog or youtube channel for beginners?

Comment: OK, So do not start with a plain ASP.NET Web Forms site, generally speak people don't build these for new sites any more. Look for tutorials on starting an MVC Core site. Build something simple, then incorporate ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: I agree with @Jammer. If you have the choice, I'll go for what he is proposing. I would suggest to take a look at Jeff Fritz's ASP.NET CORE for Beginners - an 8 Hour Workshop - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--lYHxrsLsc

Answer (score 1):

Do not use such checks in the application code.  This has a problem, because two threads could run at the same time, both would see that the user does not exist, and both would insert the same user.

Instead, let the database do the work.  Create a unique index or constraint on the table to ensure that the user name is unique (under the hood, these are really the same thing):

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_username unique (username);
```

Then, check the error being returned when you do the insert.  If you have a constraint violation, then the problem is a duplicate user name.

Also, you should not be munging query strings with user input.  Not only is that very dangerous and a really bad practice, but it can introduce really-hard-to-debug errors.  Learn to use parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. by changing my table name and its constraints  to some unique name will fix the problem?

Comment: @ShoaibSattar . . . Hopefully, your table is not really named `[Table]`.  The important point in the constraint, not the name of the table.